# Python Adding multiple data points in a dict from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file that looks like:

```
CountryCode, NumberCalled, CallPrice, CallDuration
BS,+1234567,0.20250,29
BS,+19876544,0.20250,1
US,+121234,0.01250,4
US,+1543215,0.01250,39
US,+145678,0.01250,11
US,+18765678,None,0
```

I want to be able to analyse the file to work some statistics from the data:

```
CountryCode, NumberOfTimesCalled, TotalPrice, TotalCallDuration
US, 4, 1.555, 54
```

At the moment, I have dict thats setup:

```
CalledStatistics = {}
```

When I read each line from the CSV, whats the best way to put the data into the dict? :

```
CalledStatistics['CountryCode'] = {'CallDuration', 'CallPrice', 'NumberOfTimesCalled'}
```

Would adding the second US line overwrite the first line or would the data be added based on the key 'CountryCode' ?

Comment: What is the question? You got a dictionary and everytime you read your CSV the country code will always overwrite so you would end up with a dict with keys (BS, US) and values = most recent entry, i.e. overwritten data.

Comment: Do you really mean to assign a set to `CalledStatistics['CountryCode']`?

Comment: In a dictionary KEY is a unique value, so yes, doing it this way would overwrite the VALUE. You are simply assigning a new VALUE to already existing KEY (US).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of these calls:

```
CalledStatistics['CountryCode'] = {'CallDuration', 'CallPrice', 'NumberOfTimesCalled'}
```

would overwrite the call before.

In order to calculate the sums you need, you could use a dict of dicts. Like in a for loop where you have your data in these variables: country_code, call_duration, call_price and where you would store the data in collected_statistics: (EDIT: added the first line in order to turn call_price into 0 if it's recorded as None in the data; this piece of code is meant to work with consistent data, like integers only, if there are possibly other types of data, they need to be turned into integers [or any numbers of the same type] before python can sum them)

```
call_price = call_price if call_price != None else 0

if country_code not in collected_statistics:
    collected_statistics[country_code] = {'CallDuration' : [call_duration],
                                          'CallPrice' : [call_price]}
else:
    collected_statistics[country_code]['CallDuration'] += [call_duration]
    collected_statistics[country_code]['CallPrice'] += [call_price]
```

and after the loop, for each country_code:

```
number_of_times_called[country_code] = len(collected_statistics[country_code]['CallDuration']

total_call_duration[country_code] = sum(collected_statistics[country_code]['CallDuration'])
total_price[country_code] = sum(collected_statistics[country_code]['CallPrice'])
```

OK, so finally here is a complete working script handling the example you gave:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import decimal

with open('CalledData', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

    # btw this creates a dict, not a set
    collected_statistics = {}

    for row in csv_r:

        [country_code, number_called, call_price, call_duration] = row

        # Only to avoid the first line, but would be better to have a list of available
        # (and correct) codes, and check if the country_code belongs to this list:
        if country_code != 'CountryCode':

            call_price = call_price if call_price != 'None' else 0

            if country_code not in collected_statistics:
                collected_statistics[country_code] = {'CallDuration' : [int(call_duration)],
                                                      'CallPrice' : [decimal.Decimal(call_price)]}
            else:
                collected_statistics[country_code]['CallDuration'] += [int(call_duration)]
                collected_statistics[country_code]['CallPrice'] += [decimal.Decimal(call_price)]


    for country_code in collected_statistics:
        print(str(country_code) + ":")
        print("number of times called: " + str(len(collected_statistics[country_code]['CallDuration'])))
        print("total price: " + str(sum(collected_statistics[country_code]['CallPrice'])))
        print("total call duration: " + str(sum(collected_statistics[country_code]['CallDuration'])))
```

using CalledData as a file having the exact same content you provided, it outputs:

```
$ ./test_script
BS:
number of times called: 2
total price: 0.40500
total call duration: 30
US:
number of times called: 4
total price: 0.03750
total call duration: 54
```

Comment: This won't work, because there would be **TypeError** due to having a **None** value in the last row. But it's good thinking.

Comment: Indeed. I think we can assume a price of None can be treated as if it was zero. So, the data need to be processed before being used. I edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: Not as easy as you think :) We don't know all the details. The more complicated the case gets, the more, well, complicated it gets! Have you tested it? Does it work? Imagine somewhere along in the file someone put "five" instead of 5 ;)

Comment: Awesome, I knew I needed a dict or dicts but wasn't sure how to compare or add based on the key 'CountryCode'. I've put some logic in that converts None to a 0 int.

Comment: Well I add a complete script. The type of the data is indeed important to check. I just turned them into int or decimal.Decimal, assuming these would be these kinds of types, but all different cases should be properly handled.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries can contain lists and lists of dictionaries, so you can achieve your desired structure as follows:

```
CalledStatistics['CountryCode'] =[ {
    'CallDuration':cd_val, 
    'CallPrice':cp_val,
    'NumberOfTimesCalled':ntc_val } ]
```

Then you can add values like this:

```
for line in lines:
    parts = line.split(',')
    CalledStatistics[parts.pop(0)].append({
        'CallDuration':parts[0], 
        'CallPrice':parts[1],
        'NumberOfTimesCalled':parts[2] })
```

By making each countryCode a list, you can add as many unique dicts as you want to each countryCode.

The `pop(i)` method, returns the value and mutates the list so all that remains is the data you desire for the dict values.  Thats why we pop index `0` and add index `0` - `2` to the dict.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach could be slightly different. Just read the file, make it a list (readlines.strip("\n"), split(",").

Forget about the first row and the last (will be empty most likely, test).
Then you can make the dict using an example @zezollo used and simply add values by key of the dict you would create. Make sure all the values you are adding, after you make it a list of lists, is the same Type.

Nothing like a hard work, you'll remember that case for long ;)

Test, test, test on mock examples. And read Python help and docs. It's brilliant.